# How can I prevent long equation from span two column page?

Tags: equations

[image]I have long equation with integral and summation process. how can I prevent it from span two column? I am tired using splitting and multiline but I have error missing `}` or `)`.

```
\begin{equation}

\hat{r}\left(t\right)=\frac{\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int{\left(y\left(t\right)+n\left(t\right)\right)P^\ast\left(t\right) \alpha _s\left(t\right)dt}\right)\ \gamma \left(t-mT\right)

\end{equation}
```

I want to break equation from `\alpha` to be in the second line. Any idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you were having with `split` is that you cannot have a line break between a matching `{` and `}`, or between `\left` and `\right`.

I rewrote your equation slightly so that the parentheses spanning the line break set an explicit size instead of `\left` and `\right`, and removed the unnecessary braces around the expression to be integrated.

I also removed most of the other `\left` and `\right` commands, because [they introduce unwanted spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBpIH.png) (which was especially noticeable after P*).  If you want scaled parentheses around a function argument, a good fix is `\PairedMathDelimiter` from `mathtools`.

One pair that I left in was around y(t) + n(t), although I changed them to square brackets because they surround parentheses the same height.  If you use parentheses around parentheses, you would want the outer parentheses slightly larger, with `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.

There’s no consensus on how to typeset the variable of integration *dt*, but here I give an example of how to set d in the same font as log or sin.  If you want it to look the same as the variable *d*, you can just change `{\operatorname d}` to `d`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\dint[1]{\mathop{{\operatorname d}{#1}}}
\newcommand\Pstar{P^\ast}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \hat{r}(t) = \frac{\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
      \biggl(\int \left[ y(t) + n(t) \right]
      \Pstar(t) \\
    \alpha_s(t) \dint{t} \biggr) \cdot \gamma(t-mT)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Revised equation layout]

#### Original Answer

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\dint[1]{\mathop{d{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \hat{r} \left(t\right) = \frac{\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
      \biggl(\int \left[ y\left(t\right) + n\left(t\right) \right]
      P^\ast\left(t\right) \\
    \alpha_s\left(t\right) \dint{t} \biggr)
      \cdot \gamma \left(t-mT\right)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample equation layout]

If you want more control over the alignment of the pieces of the equation, you can make the enclosing `equation` an `align` and insert alignment points with `&`.

If you would like to change the *dt* at the end of the integral to an upright d, to avoid confusion with the variable *d*, you can change the definition of `\dint` to `\mathop{{\operatorname d}{#1}}`.

Comment: `d` denotes a differential and a variable at the same time.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat True, although in this context, it’s unlikely to be confused. If the OP wants to use an upright d, they should change the definition of `\dint` to `\mathop{\mathrm{d}{#1}}`.

Comment: Just for the records (and it is fine if we disagree to disagree on this): for me typesetting the differential *operator* italic is as wrong as typesetting the sine of `t` as `$sin(t)$`  (or `$\mathit{sin}(t)$`) even if it is unlikely that this gets confused.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ISO style agrees with you. Some mathematicians here don’t. I’m just going to tell people how to do it either way and change easily.

Comment: Yes, this is an interesting discussion which we should avoid. However, one has to be a bit careful to distinguish between mathematicians who have a faculty position in computer science and mathematicians who are faculty in math departments. But I know that even among the latter a few like italic d's, which of course shows that arguments like "I do that because XY likes it" cannot be used to make conclusive statements.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes. I normally write it upright. My working assumption is that the OP did it that way intentionally, but I took your comment as a suggestion to share the code to do it the other way. So, thank you for the constructive comment.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I’ve gone back and made some fixes. One is that, I personally always make `\mathrm` the same font as `\operatorname`, but if I were using a different font for operators, I would want my upright d set as an operator.

Comment: Thank you very much. your answers and comments are helpful. I removed the unnecessary parenthesis which is solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic equation splitting mechanism are not perfect according to what I know, so I'd do it manually. Also, since you have a variable `d` in your equation, you have even more reasons to typeset differential `d`'s upright. I would not overdo it with `\left` and `\right`. Since you do not provide us with a complete document, I had to guess, and hope that the following will allow you to get what you want.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \hat{r}(t)&=\frac{\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}}
 \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma \left(t-mT\right)
 \notag\\
 &\quad
 \cdot\int
 \bigl(y(t)+n(t)\bigr)P^\ast(t)\,\alpha_s(t)\diff t
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. my question may not be clear. I need to split equation in side summation function or inside integral. I have out-summation function inside integral function inside summation. How can make break inside last summation? this is my problem. when I using split or multline I get error missing }

Comment: @hindalaskary I wouldn't use `split` at all. Having the equation number centered is IMHO not a good idea. What happens if there is a page break between the lines? You prohibit it, which can make the text flow ugly. Just put the equation number in the last line and use `align`.